# Java InputStream cannot be null loading XML

Tags: java, xml, exception

I have problem withh loading xml file. There is a sample of code

```
SAXParserFactory parserFactor = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
SAXParser parser = parserFactor.newSAXParser();
SAXHandler handler = new SAXHandler();
parser.parse(ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("testXml.xml"),handler);
```

forth line throws an exception

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: InputStream cannot be null
```

testXml.xml is located in my project folder. Any ideas ?

Comment: `ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("testXml.xml")` returns null so debug your path.

Comment: Are you sure you want to read the resource from the **system** class loader? You might want to use `getResourceAsStream` instead.

Comment: I tried absolute path as well.

Comment: Use this one. <your_class>.class.getResourceAsStream("testXml.xml");